# Can carbon monoxide contaminate water?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, water, carbonyl-compounds

Just wondering if you fitted a cold water tank overflow pipe into a car park at the height of a car exhaust , if the carbon monoxide fumes went back up the oveflow pipe into the tank would this contaminate the water?

Comment: My question is "Will Carbon Monoxide saturated water emit Carbon Monoxide from it's surface?

Answer (score 5):

Contamination would occur if a sufficient quantity of carbon monoxide wouldn't just bubble through but

1. would react with water to form an unhealthy product or
2. is dissolved in water

Both isn't really true:

1. $\ce{CO}$ does not react under these conditions.
2. The solubility of $\ce{CO}$ in water at 20 °C is as low as $\mathrm{30\,mg\cdot L^{-1}}$ ([GESTATIS database](http://gestis-en.itrust.de/nxt/gateway.dll?f=templates$fn=default.htm$vid=gestiseng:sdbeng))

Comment: Therefore a small amount of CO in the air gap above the water would really be seen as sufficient to penetrate the water surface ?

Comment: Honestly, my laziness and a stupid cold keep me from doing any calculations on that. But I'd probably drink from the water and wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: For comparison, the [allowable maximum for benzene](http://water.epa.gov/drink/contaminants/basicinformation/benzene.cfm#four) is 0.005 mg/l, so soluability of 30 mg/l doesn't mean no effect. [This guide](http://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/toxguides/toxguide-201.pdf) says there is no data on CO in drinking water.

Comment: Basically I am a plumber I went to clean a tank for a customer and my co meter alarm activated when I opened the lid. I couldnt understand why there would be co in the tank as I have maintained the tank for a few years. On investigation I found that another contractor had run the overflow pipe to the car park and a car was left running. The co has come back up the overflow into the tank.

Comment: I decided to drain the tank and ventilate until no more co was reading on the meter. I think chlorinated the tank and reinstated, just hoping its ok.

Comment: @DanG Then this is a question about safety of an actual procedure. You should be consulting an expert with appropriate training and certification, not random strangers on the internet.

Comment: Thanks for your comment David , yes I did consult the local ukas approved laboratory but felt like getting a second opinion.

Comment: @DanG I'd be more concerned about the other components in exhaust fumes which may contaminate the water, heavy metals for a start.